# In Ruby, is it ok to have a double rescue without an end?

Tags: ruby, rescue

I have some code that passes tests in rspec. It appears I don't need `end` with a double `rescue` in Ruby,  or even `begin` for that matter.  Essentially, I return `5` when a Geocoder error is encountered and `6` if a CustomError is encounted and `7` otherwise.

```
def get_stuff
  puts "some code work"
  rescue ::Geocoder::Error => e
    puts "hello"
    return 5
  rescue CustomError => e
    puts "world"
    return 6
  7
end
```

Comment: It'd probably help if you read some tutorials about using `rescue`. This is covered as part of all the Ruby books I've seen.

Comment: Function definitions have an implicit begin block. So the `rescue` is on the `def` block, same as it would be on an explicit `begin` block in other scenarios. As others have mentioned, indentation is meaningless in Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

Indentation doesn't matter in Ruby.  Technically the `7` will never be returned because you have it inside the rescue block after the `return 6` line.

If you want to return `7` when no error is raised, place it on the last line before the `rescue` blocks:

```
def get_stuff
  puts "some code work"
  7 #success!
  rescue ::Geocoder::Error => e
    puts "hello"
    return 5
  rescue CustomError => e
    puts "world"
    return 6
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A method is its own `begin`/`end` block, so you can just do `rescue` when you need it, and also `ensure` when you need it.

As you've done, you do need to do explicit `return` statements if the `rescue` or `ensure` block should return a value.

... although I'm surprised that you're getting `7` returned... that's part of your second rescue block and shouldn't return.

Comment: 7 is only indented with 2 spaces (it is inline with the rescue) whereas 6 and 5 are indented with 4 spaces, so if none of the errors are hit, won't 7 be returned?

Comment: This isn't python, this is ruby. Indentations have no significance other than improving readability.

Comment: `7` will never be returned.

Comment: Also it's not correct that `return` is required in this case.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, I substituted some values in this sample code for actual code - in this case 7 was substituted for an actual method/function call

Comment: That's fine but it won't be executed where it's located. You a would need to move it before the first rescue or insert explicit begin and end

Comment: Return is required to have a value returned from a rescue block.